# How to modify public assets directory in playframwork?

Tags: playframework

[this document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy) refers public directory as default assets path but how to modify `/public` as others?

**=======Update: to clarify new public folder place ========**

Hope use `aotherfolder` replace public folder :

project
--- app
--- wwwroot
------- **anotherfolder**
--- public
--- ...

so the `anotherfolder` under the project directory.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to use another folder as for your assets? It that other folder inside your application root directory? Please edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about changing the default folder `public`, so if you look into the `routes` file you'll see

```
GET         /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

change it to

```
GET         /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/otherfolder", file: Asset)
```

So it is defined here that go to `/public` for the assets, you can change it according to you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Seems there are some misleading.I want to achive `GET         /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/otherfolder", file: Asset)` in routes because fortend has his way to generate release file and not place under `public`.

Comment: this line `GET         /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)` is already in your routes file, now if you want to fetch assets from any other folder change this to `GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/otherfolder", file: Asset)` , If i got right what you've asked for.

Comment: It not works if not use `public` folder. A error page returns `Action Not found`.

Comment: Got your point, see this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#How-are-public-assets-packaged? , all the public folder assets are added to class path by default, you should try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395167/asset-mapping-outside-public-folder-on-play-framework , see Kris's answer.

Comment: Thanks and I think its not a good idea to define a `StaticAsset` controller replace playframework's `Assets.at` and `Assets.versioned` method, it just seems I build a wheel but less power then others. Besides, `ln -s` not work on windows even though I'm attempt with win10 `bash` environment.

Comment: How about having both? Let the original be there and create one more route as per your requirement.